# How many times I can restore Win10 OS in my laptop

Tags: laptop, lenovo-laptop, restore, system-restore

I got new 710S-13IKB IdeaPad laptop and would like to mak esome experiments on it. After each experiment I would like to restore system by using restore Lenovo system. But will Windows be happy to get activated from same hardware so many times. Or maybe they already activated?

Comment: Does the laptop have a Windows product key on the back?

Comment: There is no product key on the back.

Comment: Is Windows 7 the original operating system?

Comment: Windows 10 is original OS. I haven't changed it's original OS

Comment: Then it should be automatically activated if you reset it.

Comment: Better option is to install some virtualization software on that laptop and then you can experiment on every OS you want and restore snapshots after your testing...

Comment: Is it limited count of activation times? Does it goes on Internet for this activation?

Comment: @vico No; All you need to know is that Windows will automatically activate, don't worry about the details